# Printing from a stream in the browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, browser

I have an online viewer(popup) where Images are displayed in a div, along with some buttons to zoom in/out or rotate the image. Now I want to print the image programatically on certain user action. Is there any option to print just the from the browser or to print from a stream. I can't install extra plugins on the browser to accomplish this. If not printing an image directly, can I somehow print the image if I convert it into pdf before printing? I have tried finding a solution for this but the only thing I could find was javascript's window.print() function.The problem is that it will print the entire page including the buttons if I use it. I just want to print the image.

Comment: you can open a new window. set the content of the window to the corresponding html/img and call the new window's print function

Comment: Thought about that it wouldn't look good unless it's done silently. Is there anyway this can be done without viewer seeing the new page that I open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the media print option to set contents of the body to hidden and only the image you want to print to show. Add a wrapper to contents in the body and append the image you want to print out side the wrapper with class print and add the following css.

```
 <style type="text/css"  >
     .content-wrapper{
        display:block;
     }
     .print{
        display:none; 
     }
</style>  
<style type="text/css" media="print" >
     .content-wrapper{
        display:none;
     }
     .print{
        display:block; 
     }
</style>
```